# Javascript array filter by year

Tags: javascript

I am trying to filter an array

I keep getting back the array in full instead of just the filtered elements. How can I get it to filter elements?

```js
       const inventors = [
      { first: 'Albert', last: 'Einstein', year: 1879, passed: 1955 },
      { first: 'Isaac', last: 'Newton', year: 1643, passed: 1727 },
      { first: 'Galileo', last: 'Galilei', year: 1564, passed: 1642 },
      { first: 'Marie', last: 'Curie', year: 1867, passed: 1934 },
      { first: 'Johannes', last: 'Kepler', year: 1571, passed: 1630 },
      { first: 'Nicolaus', last: 'Copernicus', year: 1473, passed: 1543 },
      { first: 'Max', last: 'Planck', year: 1858, passed: 1947 },
      { first: 'Katherine', last: 'Blodgett', year: 1898, passed: 1979 },
      { first: 'Ada', last: 'Lovelace', year: 1815, passed: 1852 },
      { first: 'Sarah E.', last: 'Goode', year: 1855, passed: 1905 },
      { first: 'Lise', last: 'Meitner', year: 1878, passed: 1968 },
      { first: 'Hanna', last: 'Hammarström', year: 1829, passed: 1909 }
    ];



    function isOldEnough(inventor) {
      if(inventor.year >= 1500 && inventor.year <= 1600){
          return inventor;
      }
    }

    inventors.filter(isOldEnough)
    console.log(inventors);
```

Comment: You need to retain the result in something - it does not act on the array itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filter` doesn't change the array, it instead returns a new array containing just the items that matched the creteria. Use this:

```
var oldEnough = inventors.filter(isOldEnough);
```

And please make the filtering function cleaner:

```
function isOldEnough(inventor) {
  return inventor.year >= 1500 && inventor.year <= 1600;
}
```